# Clicking application logo do something other than open navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, application-icon

In my application when the user clicks on the application logo or title, system will open the navigation drawer.
I want to make the navigation drawer to be open **only** if  the navigation icon clicked, as i want to do some other logic if the user clicks application logo and title.
How to perform that ?

This code is intended to open navigation drawer upon clicking application logo, title or navigation icon.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle action bar actions click
    switch (item.getItemId()) { 
    case R.id.action_settings:
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        //return false;
    }
}
```

Any advice is appreciated

Comment: do your action in 'case android.R.id.home:'

Comment: @Harry not working. it never get in that case

Comment: Have you used setHomeButtonEnabled(true)?

Comment: Yes, and tried to remove it and tried also to use setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true). in all of the previous cases problem not solved.

Comment: To allow the control go into switch case you have to move if().. code below the switch case.

Comment: switch (item.getItemId()) { 
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        case android.R.id.home:
         Toast.makeText(this, "click app icon",
     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         return false; 
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

Comment: i have no if condition within switch code

Comment: Sorry bro! I just got it wrong, I was providing way to click logo, sorry no idea what you are asking for 'only if the navigation icon'. Use custom layouts.

Answer (score 0):

I Would advice you to create a custom Toolbar using a separate XML layout and use it in your Main layout,as it is easy.
so the imageview and text View can serve for a specific purpose when clicked!